# ASP.NET MVC ENTITY Framework - Use different databases or datasets?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I watch the Pluralsight tutorials at [asp.net/mvc](http://asp.net/mvc) from Scott Allen and I have a question about globalization. In these videos, he recommends to use Resource files (**.resx**) to store language-specific strings. 
I tried, but failed when I wanted to work with these strings from code. So I had the idea , to use a database with Entity Framework to store them.
My questions are:

1. Do I do something wrong with the Resource files ? Should I use them or not ?
2. If I shouldn't, It would be better to create a new database for texts or just add a `DataSet<>` ?

*I'm new in ASP.NET MVC, but I really like the idea, so I want to do everything right from the beginning. That's why I'm asking so "basic" questions.*

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: are you saying you want to store some string resources? If so you should use config files for this purpose

Comment: what code is failing when using resource files ? This is the best way to do it unless you have a reason to store them in the database aka they could change often or something

Comment: This is actually two questions sort of tied together. Can you describe in more detail what exactly happened when you tried to use the resource files? You may find that you want to use both, so you use .resx files to contain the text for buttons, different images if you have any text on your images and so on, then have language specific rows in your database or language specific databases, depending on how you want the system to work. There are a lot of variables here so you probably need to think about what exactly the question is and what the answer you are looking for would tell you.

Comment: Primary texts. In my example, he's building an e-shop, so let's say that these text is the "About us" page, which can be changed via a web form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Resource files.

Guy Smith-Ferrier is the best resource on this subject.

[How To Achieve World (Ready) Domination In ASP.NET MVC 4](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/aspConf/aspConf/How-To-Achieve-World-Ready-Domination-In-ASP-NET-MVC-4)

> So you’ve written your ASP.NET MVC application and you want it to work
>   in another language ? Then this session is for you. World-Readiness is
>   all of the work that a developer needs to do to globalize an
>   application and make it localizable (i.e. capable of being localized).
>   In this session we will cover localizing HTML and HTML Helpers,
>   localizing and globalizing Data Annotations, localizing and
>   globalizing JavaScript and localizing URLs. No previous experience of
>   ASP.NET localization is required.

[Slides](http://www.guysmithferrier.com/downloads/I18NMVC.pdf) and
[Source](http://www.guysmithferrier.com/downloads/I18NMVCSource.zip)

Maybe read a book: [.NET Internationalization: The Developer's Guide to Building Global Windows and Web Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321341384)

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. It answered my questions.